# getting current logged in user from one domain to another

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to pass a Current User ID from one website to another.

Example, a user signs in on users.domain.com this creates a $_SESSION['uid'] of the users id.
I need to be able to get this users id value on domain.com.

I have tried setting a session_set_cookie_params:

```
session_set_cookie_params( 0, "/", ".domain.com", false, false);
```

and this does work on my local server but not with my hosting company, probably because the session data is stored on separate servers or they simply do not allow it.

I have read many posts/answers using either $_GET,Cookie or HTTP Headers to store the users ID but I find this a very insecure way of doing it.

How does the likes of Facebook do with $facebook->getUser(); ?

Any help would be much appreciated, I have been scouring the web for a good while with no luck.

Thanks, Chris.

Comment: Do you have access to create a database table on both servers?

Comment: @Phil Crosyes yes, in fact, both sites would be connecting to the same MySQL database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer will only apply if you are able to create a database table on the original server.

I won't write the code, but its more of a guide:

1) Create a table on your original server called something like `tbl_auth_tokens` with the following fields: `record_id (auto_increment primary_key)`, `user_id (int)` and `token_id (varchar (32))`.

2) Before you redirect the user to the other domain, generate a random token, using MD5 (or some other hash function containing enough random strings to make it unique.

3) Save the users ID and token ID to the `tbl_auth_tokens` table, redirect the user to the other domain with the `token_id` in the querystring.

4) On the new server, use the provided token ID to retrieve the user ID from the original servers database, then DELETE the token record completely.

This method will at least stop the user ID being visible, and any potential evesdroppers will only see a token_id which deletes once the user has been verified on the second server.

In addition, you may want to create an auto-delete function to remove tokens after say 2 minutes of inactivity.

If you need any more guidance, feel free to comment :)