# Move the user from a domain to another and still being logged

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies, session-state

We have PHP based framework application which is based on cookies and also required log in to use certain features like action center. We are planning to move part of application on other domain hosted on same server. Is it possible move the user from a domain to another and still being logged?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use some kind of token sharing between the domains.

Cookies and Sessions cannot be transferred across domains. Read my answer in the post below, as I believe this is what you could use:

[getting current logged in user from one domain to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823879/getting-current-logged-in-user-from-one-domain-to-another/16824023#16824023)

Answer (score 0):

You need something similar to what Facebook uses. 
As they define it: The OAuth 2.0 authorization framework enables a third-party application to obtain limited access to an HTTP service.
http://oauth.net/

Good luck